# Can't parse a text file. I want to write a new file text, taking some words from an other file text

Tags: perl, parsing

Can't parse a text file. I want to write a new file text, taking some words from an other file text. it's written in Perl. VSS_Report is the handel of the original file and SVN_Report is the handle of the created file.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use FileHandle;


my $VSS_Report_Path = <STDIN>;

chomp $VSS_Report_Path;

my $SVN_Report_Path = 'C:\Users\Maurizio Ambroselli\Desktop\PerlEsercitazione\SVN_Users.ini';

if (open SVN_REPORT, "+>>", $SVN_Report_Path) {

     # Parsing del File Vss_Report

        foreach my $val (VSS_REPORT){

if ((substr my $val, 0, 11) eq 'VSS Path: $'){
                    my $Projects_temp = (substr $val, 11);
                    print SVN_REPORT my $Project_temp;
                    }

                if ((substr my $val, 0, 6) eq "User: "){
                    my $Users_temp = (substr $val, 6);
                    print SVN_REPORT "$Users_temp=";
                    }

                if ((substr my $val, 0, 13) eq "Permissions: "){
                    my $Permissions_temp = (substr $val, 13);
                    if ($Permissions_temp eq " ") {print SVN_REPORT " \n";}
                    if ($Permissions_temp eq "Read") {print SVN_REPORT "r\n";}
                    else {print SVN_REPORT "rw\n";}
                }                                                   
        }

    close SVN_REPORT;

}
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Maurizio Ambroselli\Desktop\PerlEsercitazione>perl "new 1.pl" Global symbol "$Project_temp" requires explicit package name at new 1.pl line 58. Bareword "VSS_REPORT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at new 1.pl line 55. Execution of new 1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I get this error: C:\Users\Maurizio Ambroselli\Desktop\PerlEsercitazione>perl "new 1.pl"
Bareword "VSS_REPORT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at new 1.pl line 55.
Execution of new 1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Now I have another problem:Use of uninitialized value $val in substr at new 1.pl line 56, <STDIN> line 1. Use of uninitialized value $val in substr at new 1.pl line 61, <STDIN> line 1. Use of uninitialized value $val in substr at new 1.pl line 66, <STDIN> line 1

Comment: This is also warning. Initialise $val in if its not defined.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: `$val // ''` is a method. `foreach my $value (<$fh>){ my $val = $value // ''}`

Comment: wait.....may you explain? I suppose <$fs> is m handle file, which I called VSSREPORT.....you meant that adding my $val = $val // ' ' and then the rest of the script                                                                                                    if ((substr my $val, 0, 11) eq 'VSS Path: $'){
                    my $Projects_temp = (substr $val, 11);
                    print SVN_REPORT my $Project_temp;
                    } it should work?

Comment: what if I put @array=<VSSREPORT> and then I use foreach for the array?

Comment: Well, your idea look working, but now i have this:Use of uninitialized value $Project_temp in print at new 1.pl line 65.

Comment: If it is your first program, I would suggest please read some book before going in deep. This warning also means `$Project_temp` is undefined. You can control this also in same way.

Answer (score 1):

That is not error. Its warning. You have used `VSS_REPORT` in foreach loop whereas your filehandle name is `SVN_REPORT`.

And you can't use filehandle like this in foreach loop. Keep it in `<>` or create an array of filehandle and use that array.

```
foreach my $val (<SVN_REPORT>) {
    # do something
}
```

or

```
my @VSS_REPORT = <SVN_REPORT>;
foreach my $val (@VSS_REPORT) {
    # do something
}
```

I would suggest always use lexical filehandle `$svn_report`.

Comment: wait a minute....but a warning allows the programm to complete anyway or not? Because the SVNREPORT file has been created but it is empty....

Comment: When you use a Bareword, its doesn't allow to complete the program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed by putting all the handles VSSREPORT and SVNREPORT between the commas "", wherever they appear in the script.

Comment: Now I have another problem:Use of uninitialized value $val in substr at new 1.pl line 56, <STDIN> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $val in substr at new 1.pl line 61, <STDIN> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $val in substr at new 1.pl line 66, <STDIN> line 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little confused. You open $SVN_Report_Path but never open VSS_REPORT. Which file is the source, and to which file do you wish to write. What is the purpose of the filepath you take from STDIN?

***UPDATE***

OK, now I have a better idea what you are doing. Here is a tidied up version of your script.

Can you give some example of your VSS file too?

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use FileHandle;

print "Please enter VSS Report Path/Filename > ";
my $VSS_Report_Path = <STDIN>;

chomp $VSS_Report_Path;

open my $VSS_Report, '<', $VSS_Report_Path or die "Could not read from $VSS_Report_Path: $!\n";

my $SVN_Report_Path = 'C:\Users\Maurizio Ambroselli\Desktop\PerlEsercitazione\SVN_Users.ini';

if (open my $SVN_Report, "+>>", $SVN_Report_Path) { 
    # Parsing del File Vss_Report

    while ( my $val = <$VSS_Report> ) {

        if ((substr my $val, 0, 11) eq 'VSS Path: $'){
            my $Projects_temp = (substr $val, 11);
            print $SVN_Report my $Project_temp;
        }

        if ((substr my $val, 0, 6) eq "User: "){
            my $Users_temp = (substr $val, 6);
            print $SVN_Report "$Users_temp=";
        }

        if ((substr my $val, 0, 13) eq "Permissions: "){
            my $Permissions_temp = (substr $val, 13);
            if ($Permissions_temp eq " "   ) {print SVN_REPORT " \n";}
            if ($Permissions_temp eq "Read") {print SVN_REPORT "r\n";}
            else {print $SVN_Report "rw\n";}
        }                                                   
    }
}
else {
    say "openning $SVN_Report_Path failed: $!";
}
```

Comment: sorry I deleted b mistake a line in which I use open, setting VSSREPORT as handle for the path STDIN. So the starting file is VSSREPORT, and the second one is SVNREPORT